# JS: getting all the elements for which an event is raised

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I touch the monitor of my virtual mobile phone (emulated through Chrome) the event **touchmove** is being raised.

I've tried with the following line of code and it's hit. So I'm sure that the element ".button" is being hitten by this event, **but how can I know if there are others elements which are hit before**.

```
$(".button").on("touchmove", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `target` property of the `event`. It returns the lowest level DOM Object which triggered the event:

```
$(".button").on("touchmove", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(e.target);
});
```

If you want to know what elements the event propagated through between the lowest level and the one you trapped the event on, you would need to process that manually.